# Unwanted behaviour from System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage()

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, graphics, gdi+, drawimage

Did anybody experience similar problems using the following System.Drawing.Graphics method overload?

```
public void DrawImage(Image image,
                      Rectangle destRect,
                      Rectangle srcRect,
                      GraphicsUnit srcUnit)
```

Created Visual Studio console application with the following method usage:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
    g.DrawImage(image,
                new Rectangle(new Point(50, 50), new Size(20, 20)),
                new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(20, 20)), 
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

.NET framework version: v4.0.30319

Original image:

[image]

Console app has been run on different machines, which produced different results:

Wanted result on first machine (Windows server 2008 SP1):

[image]

Unwanted result on second machine (Windows server 2008 SP2):

[image]

Comment: What is g pointing to? The graphics context of the window? Or the image? And what does your image look like? Just a black rectangle?

Comment: >> And what does your image look like? Just a black rectangle? See "Original image"

Comment: >> What is g pointing to? Graphics.FromImage(image)

Comment: You'll need to look for a humble-bug.  The image just didn't get saved.  Or did get saved but to a file in a different directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of your call is undefined, as the source and target bitmaps are the same. It will be graphics-driver-dependent what happens. This is as if you were trying to use memcpy instead of memmove when the source and target buffers are the same.